# Division of a polynomial in three variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, divisibility, factoring

I would like to demonstrate the following

*Let $f(x,y,z) \in K[x,y,z]$ a polynomial such that $f(a^n,b^n,ab)=0$; then f is divisible by $xy-z^n$.*

*Hint: use a polynomial division algorithm*

---

**EDIT**
At this link [Showing that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]^{\mu_n}$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^n)$ are isomorphic as rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381530/showing-that-mathbbcx-y-mu-n-and-mathbbcx-y-z-xy-zn-are-isom)
I found the same problem. The answer suggest:
$$ $$
If $f(x,y,z)=\sum_{i,j,k} a_{i,j,k}x^iy^jz^k$ so
$$0=f(u^n,v^n,uv)=\sum_{i,j,k} a_{i,j,k}u^{ni+k}v^{nj+k}$$
The equation $\sum_{i,j,k} a_{i,j,k}u^{ni+k}v^{nj+k}$ give some dependence relation amongst the $a_{i,j,k}$ (since the exponent of $u$ and $v$ are the same for some $i,j,k$ and since the element $u^av^b$ are indipendent over $K[x,y]$.

> Can anyone tell me what are these relations between coefficients
> $a_{i,j,k}$ they are talking of? How do they obtain? How do these
> allow me to prove that $f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z)(xy-z^n)$? TO PLEASE SOMEONE
> CAN HELP ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how the polynomial division approach would work.

**Lemma**: Any polynomial $f\in k[x,y,z]$ can be written uniquely as $q(x,y,z)(xy-z^n) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p_i(x,y)z^i$.

**Proof**: Induction on the highest power of $z$ appearing in $f$. Clearly any polynomial of degree $n-1$ or less in $z$ satisfies the statement, so suppose $f$ has degree $d\geq n$ in $z$. Write $f=\sum_{i=0}^d p_i(x,y)z^i$: then $$f= p_d(x,y)z^d + \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} p_i(x,y)z^i =$$ $$= p_d(x,y)xyz^{n-d}-p_d(x,y)z^{d-n}(xy-z^n)+\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} p_i(x,y)z^i$$ and so $f=-p_d(x,y)z^{d-n}(xy-z^n) + f'$, where $f'=p_d(x,y)xyz^{n-d}+\sum_{i=0}^{d-1} p_i(x,y)z^i$ has degree at most $d-1$ in $z$, so by the induction hypothesis we are done. $\blacksquare$

Now suppose $f$ is in the kernel of $\varphi:k[x,y,z]\to k[a,b]$ by $\varphi(x)=a^n$, $\varphi(y)=b^n$, $\varphi(z)=ab$. Writing it as above, we see that $\varphi(q(x,y,z)(xy-z^n))=\varphi(q(x,y,z))(a^nb^n-(ab)^n)=0$, so $f$ is in the kernel iff $$\varphi\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p_i(x,y)z^i\right)=0.$$

Distributing $\varphi$, we see that we should have $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p_i(a^n,b^n)(ab)^i=0$. Now I claim that no monomial $a^rb^s$ appears with nonzero coefficient in $p_i(a^n,b^n)(ab)^i$ and $p_j(a^n,b^n)(ab)^j$ for $i\neq j$: look at the residue class of the exponent of $a$ modulo $n$. If $a^rb^s$ appeared in both of those expressions with nonzero coefficient, we should have $i\equiv r \mod n$ and $j\equiv r \mod n$, or $i\equiv j\mod n$. But $0\leq i,j<n$, so $i\equiv j\mod n$ implies $i=j$. Hence the coefficient of $a^rb^s$ in $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p_i(a^n,b^n)(ab)^i$ comes from only one $p_i(a^n,b^n)(ab)^i$, so if all the coefficients of $a^rb^s$ are zero, then all the coefficients of $p_i$ are zero for all $i$.

But this exactly means that $f=q(x,y,z)(xy-z^n)$ and we're done.

Comment: How does the polynomial $p_i(x,y)$ depend on the index $i$? It is homogeneous of degree $i$?

Comment: No, why would we have that? There are no conditions on $p_i$, and that's fine.

Comment: If I understand, when $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} p_i(a^n,b^n)(ab)^i=0$, we get a linear combination of $a^rb^s$ with coefficients in $K$ but they are linearly independent on $K$ (is that right? In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381530/showing-that-mathbbcx-y-mu-n-and-mathbbcx-y-z-xy-zn-are-isom?noredirect=1&lq=1  says that $a^rb^s$ are independent on $K[a,b]$ but we have a combination with coefficients in $K$) then all the coefficients are zero. Since coefficients of $a^rb^s$ derive from a single $p_i$ then all $p_i$ are zero (I understood this part, it is only on the first I have doubts)

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So monomials $a^rb^s$ are indipenden on $K$? Non on $K[a,b]?$

Comment: What are you talking about? The monomials $a^rb^s$ live in $K[a,b]$, and they are $K$-linearly independent as elements of this $K$-algebra basically by definition.

Comment: My professor said that this procedure is wrong, as polynomials cannot be divided into $K[u,v,w]$. He says that the right way is to proceed by working in $K(u,w)[v]$ since $K(u, w)$ is a field and therefore for polynomials in a variable (i.e. $v$) you can divide it for $uv-w^n$ which has degree 1 in $v$ so the remainder will be $r=0$ or $r\in K(u,w)$. However, he specified that then we must eliminate the denominators. But I don't understand with this method where I can use the fact that $f(x^n,y^n, xy)=0$ instead in your method I understood it.Also I don't know how to eliminate the denominators

Comment: While it is true that *in general* that you can't "do division" in the multivariate setting without applying the trick you mention, the lemma proven above shows that we **can** do it in this case (or any case where our polynomial is of the form $z^n-f$ where $f$ is of degree less than $n$ in $z$). Unless you have specific questions about my proof, I think this is where I'm going to end the conversation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that $K$ is a field and $K[x, y, z]$ is the associated ring of polynomials. Unfortunately, I don't see a polynomial division solution to this...

The problem is equivalent to showing that $f(x, y, z)$ is an element of the $0$ coset of the quotient ring $K[x, y, z]/ (xy - z^n )$. Let's first consider $K[a^n, b^n, ab]$. Observe that there is a surjective homomorphism $\varphi : K[x, y, z] \rightarrow K[a^n, b^n, ab]$ where $(x, y, z) \mapsto (a^n, b^n, ab).$ Moreover, $\ker (\varphi) = (xy - z^n)$ (show why). Then by the First Isomorphism Theorem for rings, it follows that
$$K[x, y, z] / (xy - z^n) \cong K[a^n, b^n, ab].$$
(can you give the isomorphism explicitly?) The conclusion that $f(x, y, z) \in 0 + (xy - z^n)$ follows.

This form shows up in some fairly [interesting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1561821/description-of-the-algebra-of-g-invariant-polynomials-by-generators-and-relati) results.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you. In my opinion, too, we must proceed in this way.
But now a question arises: considered \begin{align} \phi: K[x,y,z] &\rightarrow K[a^n,b^n,ab]\\ (x,y,z) &\mapsto (a^n,b^n,ab) \end{align} so $$\text{Ker}(\phi)=\{ f \in K[x,y,z]: 0=\phi(f)=f(a^n,b^n,ab)\}$$   So ker$(\phi)=(xy-z^n)$ is exactly what I want to demonstrate but can't, isn't it?
How can I proceed for this equality?

Comment: We can break that into two problems: showing that $\ker (\varphi ) \subset (xy - z^n)$ and $(xy - z^n) \subset \ker (\varphi).$ For the latter, it's enough to notice that $a^n - b^n - (ab)^n = 0$. For the former, I think you'll find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381530/showing-that-mathbbcx-y-mu-n-and-mathbbcx-y-z-xy-zn-are-isom) helpful for proving the reverse inclusion.

Comment: @Izmailov Ok, thanks. The inclusion ker$(\phi)\subset(xy−z^n)$ is exactly what i can't demonstrate. I read the link you gave me; the answer to this question says $$ $$
Now, using the fact that the elements $u^av^b$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{C}[u,v]$, show that $\alpha$ is a $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$-multiple of $xy−z^n$. $$ $$
But I can't understand how it's done practically, in the calculations. Can you help me?